# How to iterate through each data in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="table_style" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ACDB</td>
      <td>agaeg@aegrg.com</td>
      <td>98900000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DEFG</td>
      <td>defg@defg.com</td>
      <td>11111112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>IJKL</td>
      <td>ijkl@ijkl.com</td>
      <td>1234323432</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am a bit confused about how to get all the data from the table using a single button. When the user click on the button i should get all the table data. I tried with the below code. I need to get all the data in a array format. So that i can save all the data to my database.

```
    $("#saveButton").click(function(event) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var dataArray = [];
    var data = table.find('td'); 
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.size() - 1; i = i + 4) {
        data.push(data[i].textContent, data[i + 1].textContent, data[i + 2].textContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure you want this in jQuery? or plain JS is enough?

Comment: doesn't matter dear. I just want an array with all the table data. So that i can use it in PHP for storing in MySql.

Comment: replace `data.push` with `dataArray.push` first :)

Comment: Yes.Done. But i am getting an error table.find is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$("#saveButton").click(function(event) {
    var data = [];
    $("#table tr").each(function(i){
        if(i != 0){
            data.push({
                id: $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html(), 
                name: $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html(), 
                email: $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html(), 
                phone: $(this).find("td:eq(3)")}).html()
            });
        }
    });
    //do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/qg6xpy39/

HTML:

```
<table class="table_style" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ACDB</td>
      <td>agaeg@aegrg.com</td>
      <td>98900000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DEFG</td>
      <td>defg@defg.com</td>
      <td>11111112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>IJKL</td>
      <td>ijkl@ijkl.com</td>
      <td>1234323432</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="saveButton">
  click
</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function(event) {
    var rows = $('#table td'); // retrieve the rows of your table
    var dataArray = [];
    $.each(rows, function(idx, elt) {
      dataArray.push($(elt).text()); // add cell text content to the data array
    });
    console.log(dataArray); // so you can check what's in the array ;-)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, in plain JavaScirpt.

use `querySelectorAll` to select all `tr`s. Then iterate in each of them and get it's `td`'s innerHTML and push it in an array.

Then use `Array.shift()` to remove the `th` elements. That is, the titles.

The code

```
function save(){
  var arr=[];
  var tr=document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  tr.forEach(function(x,y){
    arr[y]=[];
    x.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(z){
      arr[y].push(z.innerHTML);
    });
  });
  arr.shift();
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Check the below snippet.

```js
function save(){
  var arr=[];
  var tr=document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  tr.forEach(function(x,y){
    arr[y]=[];
    x.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(z){
      arr[y].push(z.innerHTML);
    });
  });
  arr.shift();
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<table class="table_style" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ACDB</td>
      <td>agaeg@aegrg.com</td>
      <td>98900000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DEFG</td>
      <td>defg@defg.com</td>
      <td>11111112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>IJKL</td>
      <td>ijkl@ijkl.com</td>
      <td>1234323432</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="save();">Save</button>
```

Comment: afaik - not all browsers will process a nodelist using `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach, again using pure javascript rather than jQuery would be to use the DOM `NodeIterator` in conjunction with an XPath via `Document.evaluate()`

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8' />
            <title>Javascript DOM Processing</title>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
                    var query='/html/body/table[@id="table"]/tbody/tr/td';


                    var xpr = document.evaluate( query, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
                    var td = xpr.iterateNext();
                    var dataTbl=[];

                    while( td ){
                        try{
                            dataTbl.push( td.textContent );
                            td=xpr.iterateNext();
                        }catch( err ){
                            alert( 'Error'+err );
                        }
                    }
                    /* The data from all table cells is now in the array */
                    alert( dataTbl.join(String.fromCharCode(10)) );
                },false);
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- content -->
            <table class="table_style" id="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr >
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>ACDB</td>
                  <td>agaeg@aegrg.com</td>
                  <td>98900000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>DEFG</td>
                  <td>defg@defg.com</td>
                  <td>11111112</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>IJKL</td>
                  <td>ijkl@ijkl.com</td>
                  <td>1234323432</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be

```
var data_arr = [];
$('#table tr').each(function() {
  data_arr.push(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
  data_arr.push(this.cells[1].innerHTML);
  data_arr.push(this.cells[2].innerHTML);
  data_arr.push(this.cells[3].innerHTML);
});
```